# How to handle multiple users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0

I have a page which has a text box at the top. When the page is loaded, the code runs for the value of text box i.e `Textbox.text= something`. The logic of that code is:

1. bring the last value of the specific column of specific table from database (Integer always)
2. add 1 to it
3. show in text box.

It works perfectly fine. But I want to know that if two users are accessing the same page how should I handle this scenario when page is loaded.

**Example** the last value in DB column was 8 when the page loaded it incremented it and showed 9 in text box.

**But what if two users loaded the page same time on different browsers it will cause problem because I don't want duplicate in my columns.**

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is before you insert into db first get the last value from the colum and then +1 the value and then insert it into db.

but there is one catch which is if your User1 and User2 are seeing **8** value in textbox and User1 clicks on button **9** will get stored in db column and then User2 clicks on button **10** value will get stored.

Comment: Actually i want the same thing which u r tawking about " if your User1 and User2 are seeing 8 value in textbox and User1 clicks on button 9 will get stored in db column and then User2 clicks on button 10 value will get stored. " in this way i can solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to load the database value into memory (e.g. a static variable) and have a method that uses a `lock` before incrementing and returning the result to the respective users. e.g.

```
private static object _syncRoot = new object();
private static int? dbValue;
public static int GetNewDbValue()
{
    if (dbValue == null)
    {
        // load db value from database
    }

    // lock ensures only one user can increment at a time
    lock (_syncRoot)
    {
        dbValue++;
        return dbValue;
    }
}
```

This will work as long as you are not running a web farm or load balancing. If you want to stay away from static, by all means you can, just make sure the object you use instead is centrally accessible.

Comment: actually iam doing this in web form at the end of the form i have to save it but i dont want repeations in (THAT textbox value).If 9 has been displayed in textbox i want 10 and 11 for two different users saving in DATABASE